# Mac Os keyboard layout in Ubuntu

Tags: xorg, keyboard-layout, macosx

After working for some time in Mac OS I realised that I quite like the position of <kbd>Command</kbd> key and various system-wide combinations it is used in, such as Command-W for closing document windows or <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Q</kbd> for quitting apps.

Form usability/ergonomics standpoint it is way more convenient for me personally to use <kbd>Alt</kbd> or <kbd>Command</kbd> key and not having to reach for <kbd>Command</kbd> key.

Since a lot of programs in Ubuntu do already support similar combinations, namely <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Q</kbd>, I wanted to re-map those to be like their Mac Os counterparts.

So, I would like to do the following remap:

```
Ctrl-W -> Alt-W
Ctrl-Q -> Alt-Q
Ctrl-C -> Alt-C
Ctrl-V -> Alt-V
```

etc

Can that be done via, say xmodmap, or any other means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can switch the alt and super keys using the keyboard configuration panel. I use xmodmap to switch the left keys and do a few more things. This setup appears to be more reliable over successive system updates. Here is my annotated .xmodmap:

```
! xmodmap for macbook keyboard.

! Vertical and horizontal mouse/touchpad scrolls like a touch screen.
! Note that 5 4 and 7 6 are reversed.
pointer = 1 2 3 5 4 7 6 8 9 10 11 12

! Switch left command and option (super and alt).
clear mod1
clear mod4
keycode 133 = Alt_L
keycode 64 = Super_L
add Mod1 = Alt_L
add mod4 = Super_L

! Right command and option are common keys that can be remapped
! using keyboard short cuts.
keycode 134 = Menu Break
keycode 108 = Pause Clear

! Map expose and dashboard to keys that can be remapped
! using keyboard short cuts.
keycode 128 = F15
keycode 212 = F16
```