# How to remap keyboard shortcuts for Ctrl + C & Ctrl + V on Xubuntu 14.04?

Tags: xubuntu, shortcut-keys

I was wondering if it's possible to remap the keyboard shortcuts for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> & <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> on Xubuntu 14.04?

I couldn't find anything in Settings Manager -> Settings Editor -> xfce4-keyboard-shortscuts nor in Settings Manager -> Keyboard -> Application Shortcuts.

Is there maybe a workaround to reassign the copy and paste keyboard shortcuts to a different one?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Something like this http://askubuntu.com/questions/56573/mac-os-keyboard-layout-in-ubuntu or on which key do you want to remap the shortcut ?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, yes something like that but I don't really understand how am I suppose to do the xmodmap thingy. I've managed to execute the xmodmap in the terminal but I'm not really getting anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I guess I figured this one out myself. To change the keys in Xubuntu, you have to enter the following in the terminal:

```
sudo xmodmap -e "remove mod4 = Super_L"
sudo xmodmap -e "add control = Super_L"
```

This worked for me, even after reboot.